# Why is the width of a dark fringe in an interference pattern much less than the width of a bright fringe?

Tags: interference

Photographs of interference fringes show that the width of dark fringes is much less than the width of bright fringes. Why is this so?

Comment: Short answer: because your eyes are lying to you.

Comment: Better short answer: because the human eye has complex dynamics that are not great for linear mapping of data.

Comment: Does anyone have photographs of double-slit interference fringes with polarised light? Looking at videos of single photon interference it seems as if the dark and bright fringes are of equal width.

Answer (score 1):

The range of intensities from bright to dark is very large and you will see from the photograph of some fringes (not on the same horizontal scale as the graph) that the dark look wider than the bright.

[image]

The eye has a much larger dynamic range (contrast ratio between the darkest and brightest colour tones that a camera can capture in a single exposure) and so interprets the light coming into the eye in a slightly different way sometime resulting in the bright fringes being brighter than the dark.

If the exposure time is increased the bright fringes become "wider".

[image]

When you look at the fringes with you eye you are looking at the difference between "very little / no light (dark fringe) and light (bright fringe) and thus see the bright fringes as wider than the dark fringe.

The graph of intensity against position shown shows that the regions where the intensity is very low are very small compared with those where the intensity is relatively higher.

Comment: True, but I recommend avoiding descriptions with words "very low," "very small" , "relatively higher" .   I can't access imgur from work, so apologies if you posted this, but a simple graph showing intensity vs position would be helpful.

Comment: I think the photograph you shared is accurate. It shows the bright fringes are wider than the dark fringes at the center and that dark fringes are wider than the bright fringes towards the top and bottom. This is probably because the fringes are hyperboloid in shape. Many textbooks argue wrongly that since the distance between bright fringes is constant, the dark fringes and the bright fringes are equal in width.

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't say which experiment was photographed, I'll assume it was a double-slit experiment.

Assuming you study only the fringes that are relatively close to the center (so that the drop in luminosity due to diffraction can be neglected), bright and dark fringes have the same width.

First, remember that intensity varies continuously, so "width" doesn't have a strict definition.

Second, the human eye (or probably processing of its perception by the brain) has different responses to light and dark. So the difference in width is mostly an optical illusion.

Comment: The point you're eliding over is that there's only a single position with zero intensity.

Comment: I'm not eluding it. The question was phrased from a experimental point of view, so it's more interesting to understand what criteria are used to decide that something is "dark" or "bright". There's no clear cut distinction, and any visual criteria can be influenced by how the eye perceives varying luminosity.